# bootstrap warning message input data

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i am going to ask a really simple perheps a stupid question.

I am trying to display the input value in the bootstrap warning message.

So if i input something like "apple"

in the warning message it should appear that "apple does not exist !!"

So how can i put the input type **`"inputSearch"`** in the beginning of the message ...!!

```
<input  type="text" id= "inputSearch" name="inputSearch">

<div class="alert alert-warning">
   // how can i put the input type "inputSearch" here
   <strong> does not exist !!</strong>
</div>
```

so how can i display the input data "inputSearch" in the warning message

Comment: @Shivi thanks for your answer, but this is not dynamic, what i want is if it really does not exists than it return the input data and say the "input data does not exists", not when ever i input anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/eddowii/rqh2461v/2/

HTML:

```
<input  type="text" id= "inputSearch" name="inputSearch">

<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <span id="textspan"></span><strong> does not exist !!</strong>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('#inputSearch').on('input', function() {
    $('#textspan').html($('#inputSearch').val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-jquery example:

```js
  var input = document.getElementById('inputSearch');
  if (input.addEventListener) {
    input.addEventListener('input', handleSearch, false);
  } else if (input.attachEvent) {
    input.attachEvent('input', handleSearch); // old IE support
  }

  function handleSearch(evt) {
    var input = document.getElementById('inputSearch');
    var span = document.getElementById('textSpan');
    span.textContent = input.value;
  }
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="inputSearch" name="inputSearch">

  <div>
    <span id="textSpan"></span><strong> does not exist !!</strong>
  </div>
```